# Gmail API Access Single User Without Domain Wide Delegation

Tags: gmail-api

We have a bit of a dilemma that we are running into with a couple applications that are trying to read a given users email without user interaction to authorize. The key to this approach is that we want no user interaction, and want to load the client server application with the proper JSON credentials downloaded from the Google Developer Console.

I have this approach working for programs where we create a service account in the Developer Console, and then delegate domain wide authority to that account with the proper scope access. However what we are hoping is that we don't have to delegate domain wide authority, and just read the users email who created this developer console project. I have tried many different types of solutions for this, but always run into the same limitation that I have to grant domain wide access.

What I am wondering is if there is any way to gain access to a single users mailbox using a server to server type approach and not have to grant domain wide access?

I appreciate your help with this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported authorization flow for what you want to do.  You must either use a service account that has been delegated domain-wide authority, or you must use a 3LO flow that involves user consent.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. That is what I thought, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking any options. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're looking for [OAuth for Server to Server Application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). You will also be using a service account. But, granting of domain-wide authority for service accounts is an optional thing. You don't have to enable it if you don't want to.

> To support server-to-server interactions, first create a service
>   account for your project in the Developers Console. If you want to
>   access user data for users in your Google Apps domain, then delegate
>   domain-wide access to the service account.
>
> Then, your application prepares to make authorized API calls by using
>   the service account's credentials to request an access token from the
>   OAuth 2.0 auth server.
>
> Finally, your application can use the access token to call Google
>   APIs.

Comment: Domain-wide access is opional, indeed, but without it, you won't be able to access any GApps data, just your own app data.